# 10 Gbit NAS for home network limited by SATA data limit

Tags: networking, ssd, sata, nas

I need a lot of data access for my machine learning work. My home network is a 1 Gbit setup with a QNAP NAS and ditto switch. This works fairly well but is rather slow when I process large amounts of data. I bought a dedicated SSD for my workstation, that works, but what I actually want is a fast NAS that delivers data over a fast network. My workstation already has a 10 Gbit network card and I want to upgrade the NAS and the switch. Theoretically I could speed my network access 10-fold.

The problem is in the NAS. I currently have a QNAP TS 253 pro and I can upgrade to for example a TVS-951X, containing 5 bays for 3.5" units and 4 2.5" bays for M.2 units. The trouble is that all bays have a SATA III connection which limit the throughput to about 6Gbit/s. When I see [reviews of this thing](https://www.servethehome.com/qnap-tvs-951x-9-bay-nas-smb-edge-content-creators/6/) this neatly comes out. This is a waste for the M.2 disks as they could easily get to the theoretical maximum speed of 10 Gbit/s.

Is there any way to overcome this speed limit or are there systems that connect directly to the M.2 interface bypassing the SATA? I am looking to systems with a Linux type OS. The constraint is money. It is a home system so I intend to cap my spending at about $1000.

Comment: The TVS-951X does not have any M.2 slots though? Either way, hardware recommendations are off-topic on Super User.

Comment: A thousand dollar and you want the most state of the art access with disks that could easily take a quarter or more of that budget. Huh ... as for 10 Gb and 6 Gb don't forget that both have an overhead. Using a RAID0 could improve speed. As mentioned Hardware recommendations are off-topic. You might do better by optimizing your machine learning technique and just reduce disk I/O.

Comment: A NAS with multiple disks in RAID 0 (or 5 or 6 or any "stripe" method) could *theoretically* saturate multiple SATA links and achieve >10gbps overall. It depends a lot on the chipset and how the board was designed...

Comment: Sorry for asking the question in the wrong forum. @Mokubai, thanks for your explanation!